# iText - PdfActions not working

Tags: java, itext

Good Morning,
I've been following the Merge with TOC examples and not having any luck getting the PdfActions to respond.  Here is my snippet:

```
PdfReader finalReader = new PdfReader(viewableStream.toByteArray());
Document finalDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
PdfCopy finalPdfCopy = new PdfCopy(finalDoc,stream);
PdfCopy.PageStamp finalPdfStamp;
finalDoc.open();

int finalNumPages = finalReader.getNumberOfPages();
for(int finalPageIndex = 1;finalPageIndex <= finalNumPages;finalPageIndex++) {
    PdfImportedPage finalImpPage = finalPdfCopy.getImportedPage(finalReader,finalPageIndex);
    finalPdfStamp = finalPdfCopy.createPageStamp(finalImpPage);
    if (finalPageIndex == tocPage) {
       new TOCCustomizer().generateLinks(finalDoc, finalPdfCopy, finalPdfStamp, finalImpPage, vApp.getBookBuildContext(), book);
    }
    finalPdfStamp.alterContents();
    finalPdfCopy.addPage(finalImpPage);
 }
 finalDoc.close();
 finalPdfCopy.close();
 stream.flush();
 stream.close();
```

generateLinks method:

```
public void generateLinks(Document finalDoc,PdfCopy finalPdfCopy,PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp,PdfImportedPage srcPage,BookBuilderContext context, Book book) throws Exception
{
  finalDoc.setMargins(0.75f * 72, 0.75f * 72, 0.75f * 72, 0.75f * 72);
  finalDoc.add(new Paragraph(" "));

  File fontFile = new File(context.getResourcePath(), "ProximaNova-Reg.otf");
  BaseFont bfRegular = BaseFont.createFont(
        fontFile.getAbsolutePath(),
        BaseFont.CP1252,
        BaseFont.EMBEDDED
  );

  Font font1 = new Font(bfRegular,14, Font.NORMAL, Colors.SLATE_GREY);

  // create a table for the content
  PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
  table.setTotalWidth(7.5f*72);
  table.setWidths(new float[]{32f,458f,50f});

  int currentPage = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < book.getNumSections(); i++)
  {
     v.bookmodel.Section s = book.getSection(i);
     String itemNbr = s.getItemNbr();

     // don't add excluded sections
     if (s.isIncluded() && !TOC_EXCLUDE.contains(itemNbr))
     {
        PdfPCell sectNumCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(i+". ",font1));
        sectNumCell.setBorder(0);
        sectNumCell.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        sectNumCell.setPaddingLeft(5);
        sectNumCell.setPaddingBottom(10);
        sectNumCell.setPaddingTop(15);
        table.addCell(sectNumCell);

        Chunk sectChunk = new Chunk(s.getSectionName());

        sectChunk.setFont(font1);
//            sectChunk.setAction(PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(currentPage, new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FITH), finalPdfCopy));
        sectChunk.setAction(new PdfAction(PdfAction.FIRSTPAGE));

        Phrase sectPhrase = new Phrase(sectChunk);
        PdfPCell sectDescCell = new PdfPCell(sectPhrase);
        sectDescCell.setBorder(0);
        sectDescCell.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
        sectDescCell.setPaddingLeft(5);
        sectDescCell.setPaddingBottom(10);
        sectDescCell.setPaddingTop(15);
        table.addCell(sectDescCell);

        PdfPCell sectPageCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(currentPage+"",font1));
        sectPageCell.setBorder(0);
        sectPageCell.setHorizontalAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        sectPageCell.setPaddingLeft(5);
        sectPageCell.setPaddingBottom(10);
        sectPageCell.setPaddingTop(15);
        table.addCell(sectPageCell);

        int sectionPages = s.getSectionTotalPages();
        currentPage+=sectionPages;
     } else if (s.isIncluded() && TOC_SECTIONS.contains(itemNbr)) {
        int sectionPages = s.getSectionTotalPages();
        currentPage+=sectionPages;
     }
  }
```

The document is getting created, but the TOC links will not go back to the first page.  I did convert this to use PdfWriter instead of PdfCopy and this worked for the links, but I can't use PdfWriter due to the different original pdf boxing.  I think there's something simple that I'm missing, but struggling to see what it is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm currently using version 2.0.7 on this project.

Thanks In Advance,
-Jeff

Comment: The examples on developers.itextpdf.com are made with iText 5.5.11 in mind. There is no guarantee that they will work with a version that is 10 years old.

Comment: Thanks Amedee, I did upgrade to version 5.5.11 like you suggested and received the same result.

Comment: I added a Chunk on the first page and referenced this as an action on the TOC page using setLocalDestination and setLocalGoto, but both of these failed as well.

Comment: I was able to solve this.  Looks like you have to use the PdfAnnotations/stamper.addAnnotation just like Brunos Merge TOC 2 example when using PdfCopy.